# Поиск таблицы в бд

Tags: база-данных, sql

Доброго времени суток! Такая шляпа - есть база данных с тучей таблиц. Нужно найти таблицу, которая содержит пути к фотографиям пользователей - можно ли это как-то сделать? Вручную лопатить не вариант. Сервер `ms sql server 2005`.

Comment: раз есть субд значит кто-то ее использует. используйте интерфейс (веб сайт/программу) для того чтоб дергать интересующий вас функционал + цепляете какой-то монитор sql запросов или включаете логгирование запросов на стороне интерфейсаили/ субд

Answer (score 3):

Если вы знаете имя любого столбца в таблице, то - не проблема:

```
select  table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='photo'
```

Comment: Не знаю. Других вариантов нет?

Comment: Почему нет. Поиск по содержимому, если, конечно, вы его знаете.
Пишите динамический запрос с двойным циклом - первый перебирает таблицы, а второй - столбцы в таблице.

Comment: Может просто посмотреть все таблицы, которые связаны с таблицей пользователей?:) Если бд нормально построена то таблицы по идее должны быть соединены.

Comment: бд построена абы как ( нифига не понятно